# Cannot show the twitter feed it's 404 get error

Tags: javascript, twitter

Twitter feed - when opening with HTML it works. But when it's updated with Localhost or Server then it's getting 404 error and feed not showing.

```
 <a class="twitter-timeline" id="twitter-wjs" data-width="400" data-height="200"
                                data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets
                                by
                                TwitterDev</a>    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: It has been fixed as this issue
[twittercommunity.com...149252](https://twittercommunity.com/t/embedded-timeline-creation-throws-error-requesting-cdn-syndication-twimg-com/149252)